# How to fix 'Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am able to run a console web application that I wrote without any problems and get the desired output, which is displaying messages back to the command prompt.

However, I have now referenced this web app into a console application and I am now getting the error described in the title.

I have tried deleting the `localhost` certificates from MMC manually, in 'Certificates - Current User' and 'Certificates - Trusted Root Certification Authorities'. I have also tried going into the visual studio command prompt and executing `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` then ``` dotnet dev-certs https`` as well as ```dotnet dev-certs https --trust`` I have executed using `verbose` as well which did not change the outcome.

I have also repaired IIS 10.0 Express and restarted my laptop in order to acquire the `IIS Express Development Certificate`

Console App C# (Program.cs):

```
namespace Rapiscan264_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] argsWeb = new string[] { "192.168.2.2", "1234" };
            WebApplication1.Program.Main(argsWeb);
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Web App C# (Program.cs):

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HALO REST Server Simulator Copyright 2019\n");

            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.2");
            int port = 1234;

            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"*ERROR* - Number of Arguments Passed to Startup Incorrect, Expected 2 but Received { args.Length }!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!IPAddress.TryParse(args[0], out ipAddress))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"*ERROR* - Invalid IP Address Configured, IP={ args[0] }\n");
                }

                if (!int.TryParse(args[1], out port))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"*ERROR* - Invalid Port Configured, Port={ args[1] }\n");
                }
            }


            string url = $"https://{ ipAddress.ToString() }:{ port.ToString() }";
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting REST Server with URL = { url }\n");
             CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("https://192.168.2.2:1234")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);           
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            env.EnvironmentName = "Development";
            env.WebRootPath = "C:\\Users\\jch\\source\\repos\\Rapiscan264-3\\WebApplicationSourceCode\\wwwroot";
            env.ContentRootPath = "C:\\Users\\jch\\source\\repos\\Rapiscan264-3\\WebApplicationSourceCode";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Just to reiterate without the console app or setting the web application as the startup application works fine and normally I would include expected results but it is just a lot of text from a console application.

I assume the problem has to be to do with the certificate or there may be a conflict, that I am not seeing.

EDIT: I should also mention I am on Windows 10. And when I excute ```dotnet dev-certs https --check`` I get the message "A valid certificate was found."